# OpenTok incoming video streams getting attached to the bottom of the body

Tags: javascript, opentok, tokbox

Incoming video streams are getting attached at the bottom of the body. In my html I have the two divs:

```
<div id="myPublisherDiv" style="width:320px; height:240px; background-color:#ffffff"></div>
<div id="remoteVideo" style="width:320px; height:240px; background-color:#ffffff"></div>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
var remoteVideo = document.getElementById('remoteVideo');
var apiKey = "xxxx";
var sessionId = "xxxx";
var token = "xxxx";
var publisher = TB.initPublisher(apiKey, 'myPublisherDiv');
var session = TB.initSession(sessionId);

session.addEventListener('sessionConnected', function(e){
   session.publish( publisher );
   for (var i = 0; i < e.streams.length; i++) {
      if (e.streams[i].connection.connectionId == session.connection.connectionId) {
        return;
      }
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.setAttribute('id', 'stream' + e.streams[i].streamId);
      remoteVideo.appendChild(div);
      session.subscribe(e.streams[i]);
   }
});

session.addEventListener('streamCreated', function(e){
   for (var i = 0; i < e.streams.length; i++) {
      if (e.streams[i].connection.connectionId == session.connection.connectionId) {
         return;
      }
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.setAttribute('id', 'stream' + e.streams[i].streamId);
      remoteVideo.appendChild(div);
      session.subscribe(e.streams[i], div.id);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `sessionConnected` event handler, you need to pass in the div id to the `subscribe` function. ([Documentation](http://tokbox.com/opentok/webrtc/docs/js/reference/Session.html#subscribe))

```
session.subscribe(e.streams[i], div.id);
```